# Android Html.fromHtml(String) doesnt work

Tags: android, html, fromhtml

I want to set String with HTML tags effects. By using following method I am not able to do that. Its showing me normal text.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static Spanned fromHtml(String html){
        Spanned result;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            result = Html.fromHtml(html,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
        } else {
            result = Html.fromHtml(html);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I am passing following string to function;

> vgdgffdgdgfdfgdfgdfgdfgdfg..........
>
> *aererwerewrwerwer*
>
> ### *yyiyuiuuyuuyiyiuy*
>
> > hjjgjhghghgjhgjhgj
>
> - gtttggttt
> - ghgggggg

But when I apply Html.fromHtml(html); its return following string

> vgdgffdgdgfdfgdfgdfgdfgdfg.......... aererwerewrwerwer yyiyuiuuyuuyiyiuy hjjgjhghghgjhgjhgj gtttggtttghgggggg

I am running my app in emulator with API 23

Please provide some solution to handle HTML tags.

Comment: You shouldn't quote your code. You should put it in a code block so the markup doesn't get rendered.

Comment: you have to pass html text with html tags then it can show it

Comment: i have posted answer try like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android support some Html tags. you can see supported tags by android.

[Supproted Html Tag by Android](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

Android not support **ul** and **li** tags. for that you have to handle tags like below

```
public class HtmlTagHandler implements Html.TagHandler {
boolean first = true;
String parent = null;
int index = 1;
private int mListItemCount = 0;
private Vector<String> mListParents = new Vector<String>();

@Override
public void handleTag(final boolean opening, final String tag, Editable output, final XMLReader xmlReader) {

    if (tag.equals("ul") || tag.equals("ol") || tag.equals("dd")) {
        if (opening) {
            mListParents.add(tag);
        } else mListParents.remove(tag);

        mListItemCount = 0;
    } else if (tag.equals("li") && !opening) {
        handleListTag(output);
    } else if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("code")) {
        if (opening) {
            output.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("monospace"), output.length(), output.length(), Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
        } else {
            Log.d("COde Tag", "Code tag encountered");
            Object obj = getLast(output, TypefaceSpan.class);
            int where = output.getSpanStart(obj);

            output.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("monospace"), where, output.length(), 0);
        }
    }

}

private Object getLast(Editable text, Class kind) {
    Object[] objs = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), kind);
    if (objs.length == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        for (int i = objs.length; i > 0; i--) {
            if (text.getSpanFlags(objs[i - 1]) == Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK) {
                return objs[i - 1];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

private void handleListTag(Editable output) {
    if (mListParents.lastElement().equals("ul")) {
        output.append("\n");
        String[] split = output.toString().split("\n");

        int lastIndex = split.length - 1;
        int start = output.length() - split[lastIndex].length() - 1;
        output.setSpan(new BulletSpan(15 * mListParents.size()), start, output.length(), 0);
    } else if (mListParents.lastElement().equals("ol")) {
        mListItemCount++;

        output.append("\n");
        String[] split = output.toString().split("\n");

        int lastIndex = split.length - 1;
        int start = output.length() - split[lastIndex].length() - 1;
        output.insert(start, mListItemCount + ". ");
        output.setSpan(new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(15 * mListParents.size()), start, output.length(), 0);
    }
}

}
```

Now you just have to create list item string with **ul** or **li** tag like below. In this method you just have to pass array of strings which you want to show as html list.

```
 public static String getHtmlText(String[] s) {
    String ulStart = "<ul>";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        ulStart += "<li>" + s[i] + "</li>";
    }

    ulStart += "</ul>";
    return ulStart;
}
```

You can use like this:

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString, null, new HtmlTagHandler()));
```

Comment: But HTML String is getting from server through webservice. In the following format;


<p>vgdgffdgdgfdfgdfgdfgdfgdfg..........</p>\n\n<p><em>aererwerewrwerwer</em></p>\n\n<h2><span class="marker"><em>yyiyuiuuyuuyiyiuy</em></span></h2>\n\n<blockquote>
<p><samp>hjjgjhghghgjhgjhgj</samp></p>\n</blockquote>\n\n<ul>\n\t<li>gtttggttt</li>\n\t<li>ghgggggg&nbsp;</li>\n</ul>\n

how to handle it?

Comment: then try like just textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString, null, null,new HtmlTagHandler()));

Comment: you  are getting text from web in html form just you have to check all tag which is used in strings are supported by android or not if not then you have to code in tag handler class for that unsupported tag